# jquery letter and number buttons

Tags: jquery, button, search

```js
$(function() {
    $('.btn').on("click", function() {
        
   var letter = $(this).text()[0];
    $('.myClass').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text()[0] == letter) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }

  });
        
   var id = this.id;
    if (id == 'allLetter') {
    $('.myClass').show();
  }
   
    $('.btn').removeClass('letterClassOnClick');
  $(this).addClass('letterClassOnClick');
         
});
});
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="aLetter" type="button">A</button>
.
.
<button class="btn" id="zLetter" type="button">Z</button>


<button class="btn" id="btn0" type="button">0</button>
.
.
<button class="btn" id="btn9" type="button">9</button>
```

[is it possible to reduce the number of buttons to one button?
E.g. 0 - 9 and then call up all myClass elements that start with a number. see image please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdtl7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add buttons via jQuery and don't write them via HTML, it makes your code ugly. First add all of your buttons in an array then loop through them. like so:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    #buttonsParentElement{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .btn{
        background: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #7755ff;
        border-radius: 2px;
        color: #7755ff;
    }
</style>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

// Add buttons when document ready
    var buttons = [{"text": "A", "id" : "aLetter"}, {"text": "B", "id" : "bLetter"}, {"text": "C", "id" : "cLetter"}, {"text": "0", "id" : "btn0"}, {"text": "1", "id" : "btn1"}, {"text": "9", "id" : "btn9"}];
    for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
      var btn = buttons[i]; 
      $("#buttonsParentElement").append('<button class="btn" id="'+btn.id+'" type="button">'+btn.text+'</button>');
    }
    
// Handle on click event
    $("body").on("click", ".btn", function () {

        var letter = $(this).text()[0];
        $('.myClass').each(function() {
          ($(this).text()[0] == letter)?$(this).show():$(this).hide();
        });

        var id = this.id;
        if (id == 'allLetter') {
          $('.myClass').show();
        }

        $('.btn').removeClass('letterClassOnClick');
        $(this).addClass('letterClassOnClick');

    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="buttonsParentElement"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Amir. I am new to javscript and jquery is much more difficult for me. But my question is how do I reduce the number buttons to one like the one in the picture? I want to display all the elements in the class myClass a that start with a number with one click with 0-9 button.

Comment: The image is not a button, It is bunch of buttons or <a> tags that stick together with css. Can you send me link of the website you saw this image?  Then I give you the code. But first copy and paste my code, and see the result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Amir.
i solved my problem with regexp.
the --> var RegExp = /^[0-9].*$/ <-- was what I needed.
your code is great and i use it.
afterwards many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Your welcome, you can mark my answer as best answer and vote up.

Comment: i'm sorry but it doesn't work because i have less than 15 reputations.

Comment: No problem, you will prosper very soon. Wish best for you.

Comment: thank you amir. I also wish you all the best